# embedding cocos2d in storyboard project

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a running cocos2d project and a running ios storyboard project that both run without errors , when i try to embed cocos2d project into the main project i have the following errors (After disabling ARC and adding required frameworks ):

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
  "_gzread", referenced from:
      _ccInflateGZipFile in ZipUtils.o
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      _inflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      _inflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
  "*inflateInit2*", referenced from:
      _inflateMemoryWithHint in ZipUtils.o
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      _ccInflateCCZFile in ZipUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you wanting to disable ARC? How are you adding the frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `libz.dylib` library to the Link Binaries build phase or add `-lz` as other linker flag in Build Settings. Both will ensure the app is linked with the zip library needed by cocos2d.